# Bufferoverflow attack shell code address calculation

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, exploit-development, code-execution

I've completed a bufferoverflow attack by injecting shellcode into buffer, and executing exploit by:

```
./binary $(python -c 'print overflow +shellcode + adressofshellcode')
```

Above exploit is working and I'm able to exploit the binary successfully. But when I turn off or log off my VM and then try again with exploit string it is not working because `adressofshellcode` changed and my exploit points to wrong memory location, because every time program buffer is loaded into different memory location.

I'm compiling program with `-fno-stack-protector -z execstack` flags of `gcc` and my ASLR is also disabled.

Is there any way so my return address always point to shellcode?

Comment: The [traditional way](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html) to handle this is using NOP sleds. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775186/buffer-overflow-works-in-gdb-but-not-without-it/17775966#17775966 and https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16706/what-causes-the-need-for-nop-sleds